# Using a non-static custom class in static void main

Tags: c#

I am following this C# tutorial http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson20 and this is a beginner question.

Below I am creating a new Dictionary collection **Customers** of **Customer** public but not static class. The simple issue is I can't use the `customers.Add` line in my `static void main` method. What am I missing here? Must the **customers** be static too? what should i do here to be able to create **Customers** object.

```
Dictionary<int, Customer> customers = new Dictionary<int, Customer>();

Customer cust1 = new Customer(1, "Cust 1");
Customer cust2 = new Customer(2, "Cust 2");
Customer cust3 = new Customer(3, "Cust 3");

customers.Add(cust1.ID, cust1);
customers.Add(cust2.ID, cust2);
customers.Add(cust3.ID, cust3);

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Customer> custKeyVal in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Customer ID: {0}, Name: {1}",
        custKeyVal.Key,
        custKeyVal.Value.Name);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're getting, and what line is it on?  There isn't anything wrong with the code that you have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. I can't open the link you posted but I'm guessing you misunderstood something along the way.

You cannot access non-static members of a class from a static context. Let me explain...

```
class Foo
{
    int id;
    static void doStuff()
    {
        id++; // <-- Error!
    }
}
```

but this is fine:

```
class Foo
{
    static void doStuff()
    {
        var fooBar = new Dictionary<Foo, Bar>(); // Create instance
        fooBar.Add(new Foo(), new Bar()); // No error :)
    }
}
```

And for that matter, so is this (notice I'm referencing `id` as a member of `foo`):

```
class Foo
{
    int id;
    static void doStuff()
    {
        var foo = new Foo(); // Create instance
        foo.id++; // No error :)
    }
}
```

Just make sure your program class looks something like this...

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, Customer> customers = new Dictionary<int, Customer>();

        Customer cust1 = new Customer(1, "Cust 1");
        Customer cust2 = new Customer(2, "Cust 2");
        Customer cust3 = new Customer(3, "Cust 3");

        customers.Add(cust1.ID, cust1);
        customers.Add(cust2.ID, cust2);
        customers.Add(cust3.ID, cust3);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Customer> custKeyVal in customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Customer ID: {0}, Name: {1}",
                custKeyVal.Key,
                custKeyVal.Value.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so basically the Dictionary object has to be created + initialized within the void main() :) thanks

Comment: Correct. If you declared it outside of `Main`, it would be a non-static member of `Program` (unless of course you declared it as `Dictionary<int, Customer> static customers`, in which case it would work just fine.